# F# / FSharp Generic Types with Comparison for Binary Tree from wikibooks.org

Tags: generics, f#

I'm trying to implement a basic Red/Black tree in Fsharp, based public code (http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Advanced_Data_Structures)

But I keep running into problems at compile time with the final signature:

```
type 'a BinaryTree(inner : 'a tree) =
    member this.head = Tree.head inner
    member this.left = BinaryTree(Tree.left inner)
    member this.right = BinaryTree(Tree.right inner)
    member this.exists item = Tree.exists item inner
    member this.insert item = BinaryTree(Tree.insert item inner)
    member this.print() = Tree.print 0 inner
    static member empty = BinaryTree<'a>(E)
```

Specifically it gives me an error that "A type parameter is missing a constraint 'a when: comparison'" but every thing I've tried to add it hasn't worked.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try re-write a type declaration as

```
type BinaryTree<'a when 'a : comparison> (inner : 'a tree) =
```

I think there is no way to specify constraint on type parameter when you are using 'prefix' generic notation in class declaration

Comment: That did it. 

Clarification: what do you mean by 'prefix' generic notation, and what are the other possibilities?

Comment: @BioInfoBrett: prefix is `type 'a BinaryTree(/*...*/) =` and the other is `type BinaryTree<'a>(/*...*/) =`  The second option allows you to insert `when 'a : comparison` as in the example.